# ¿Cómo se le dice a la cría de un ratón?

Tags: vocabulario, solicitud-de-término

Leyendo la primera entrada para cachorro en el DLE parece que dicha palabra sería una opción:

> [**cachorro, rra**](https://dle.rae.es/?id=6YX4L3h)
>
> Del lat. *catŭlus*.
>
> 1. m. y f. Cría del perro y de algunos mamíferos, como el león, el lobo, el oso, etc.

Pero, algunos de los ejemplos allí listados tienen su propio término para designar a las crías:

- **Lobo**: [Lobezno](https://dle.rae.es/?id=NXQmVb8), [lobato](https://dle.rae.es/?id=NXAFshA).
- **Oso**: [Osezno](https://dle.rae.es/?id=RHyuQpq).

Y otros que encontré:

- **Perro**: [Perrezno](https://dle.rae.es/?id=SiT2gTE).
- **Jabalí**: [Jabato](https://dle.rae.es/?id=MG9BR5A).

¿Existe algún término que sea específico para la cría de ratón?

Comment: En el conejo se les llama gazapos, no sé si será aplicable a otros roedores

Comment: lo de perezno no lo había oído nunca, yo uso cachorro

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No parece que haya un término para designar a las crías de ningún roedor, ni en general ni en particular. Lo más que he encontrado es esto:

> **[sorce](https://dle.rae.es/?id=YPacBFt)**
>
> Del lat. *sorex*, *-ĭcis*.
>
> 1. m. desus. Ratón pequeño.

Tan en desuso que en el CORDE solo hay casos de alrededor del año 1400. El caso es que no designa a las crías, sino a ratones de tamaño pequeño. Así que me temo que habrá que usar el genérico *[cría](https://dle.rae.es/?id=BFmdoU8)*.

También podríamos echar mano de los sufijos. Existen dos documentados:

> **[-ato<sup>1</sup>, ta](https://dle.rae.es/?id=4GZKKGk)**
>
> Del lat. *-ātus* o *-ātum*.
>
> 4. suf. Aplicado a nombres de animales, designa la cría. *Cervato, ballenato.*

Y:

> **[-ezno, na](https://dle.rae.es/?id=HQyYOIe)**
>
> Del lat. *-icĭnus*.
>
> 1. suf. Se aplica a nombres de animales para construir otros sustantivos, frecuentemente con valor diminutivo, que designan la cría. *Lobezno, osezno, pavezno.*

El problema es que ni *ratonato* ni *ratonezno* parecen tener mucho tirón lingüístico. Por lo que otra sugerencia sería usar un diminutivo genérico: *ratoncillo*.

---

Aunque no tiene que ver con la pregunta, no puedo dejar de mencionar lo que dice Covarrubias en su diccionario de 1611 sobre los ratones:

> RATON, animal sucio que suele engendrarse de la corrupcion, aunque tambien se multiplica por generacion.

Vamos, que los ratones pueden o bien aparearse y tener crías, o bien aparecer espontáneamente en cualquier sitio donde haya suciedad.

Comment: *Ratonezno* es rara de pronunciar pero *ratonato* suena bastante bien

Comment: ¡Qué palabra tan bonita, Charlie! En italiano existe la palabra *sorcio*, que tiene una versión arcaica o regional *sorce* (y también *sorco*, usado, por ejemplo, por Dante). Pero lo curioso es que significa "ratón" en general y no "ratón pequeño".

Answer (score 2):

Similar al desusado *sorce*, en Cuba, puede decir:

> #### [guayabito](https://dle.rae.es/?id=Jmz45mT)
>
> 1. ```
>    m. Cuba.
>    ```
>
>    Ratón pequeño.

Answer (score 2):

En Puerto Rico se le llama a la cría del ratón y la rata arriero, vulgarmente llamado rajiero:

> #### rajiero
>
> 1. Arriero. Ratón pequeño muy roedor.
> 2. a. Ratoncito.

- [Tesoro lexicográfico del español de Puerto Rico](https://tesoro.pr/lema/rajiero)